# Install module cbpro throws multiple errors in several other projects (python 3.10, pycharm)

Tags: python, pycharm, coinbase-api

I have made a few projects which run fine. A new project required me to install `pip install cbpro` (a module for dealing with coinbase cryptocurrency API).

After installing it, even running the simplest code throws several errors:

Input:

```
import cbpro
```

import pandas as pd
c = cbpro.PublicClient()

data = pd.DataFrame(c.get_products())
data.tail().T

```
Errors:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/PycharmProjects/stonks/coinbase_interface.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cbpro
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cbpro/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from cbpro.authenticated_client import AuthenticatedClient
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cbpro/authenticated_client.py", line 10, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/utils.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .cookies import RequestsCookieJar, cookiejar_from_dict
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/cookies.py", line 174, in <module>
    class RequestsCookieJar(cookielib.CookieJar, collections.MutableMapping):
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
```

Secondly, when I then go to other projects that were working well, I get additional errors. Of note, those projects start with:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
```

Errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/PycharmProjects/stonks/historical_crypto_pull.py", line 2, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/utils.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .cookies import RequestsCookieJar, cookiejar_from_dict
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/cookies.py", line 174, in <module>
    class RequestsCookieJar(cookielib.CookieJar, collections.MutableMapping):
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
```

**Things I've tried:**

- If I uninstall `cbpro`, then uninstall and reinstall `requests`, I can undo the error and am back where I started. However, I'm interested in knowing why I am encountering these errors because I'd like to actually use cbpro and know how to solve this issue in the future.

Comment: The libraries you are using are not compatible with Python 3.10. They are using deprecated module structure.

Comment: Thanks! This might make sense because my friend did not have these errors and is using an older version. However, he is also using Windows so I wondered if it might have something to do with the way terminal downloaded the directories or set the paths. 

When I get this error, is there a way to tell that this is a version incompatibility issue? I couldn’t find any documentation online that suggested that might be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The libraries I was using were not compatible with Python 3.10. I am still at a loss for how I would inherently know that based on the errors thrown, but since then my solution was to install Python 3.9 and see if I still get the same errors when running 3.9.

(Then I also read that it might be a better idea for my current purposes to use a slightly older version of Python, so I moved over to 3.9 completely and haven't had the same issue again.)

Comment: "I can't seem to mark MisterMiyagi's answer since it was in the comment section." No need to. Self-answering is completely fine – just mark your own answer as correct.